# How to get the size of an inherited form in the base form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-inheritance

Suppose you have a form called `FormBase` and all other forms inherit from this form.
For example, I have `public class Form formTest : FormBase`

What I have now in the ctor of formTest:

```
public class Form formTest : FormBase
{
    public formTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Program.MainForm.AddToFormSizes(this, this.Size);
    }
}
```

This code adds the instance of `formTest` to a dictionary on the mainform with its `size`

This works, but I would like to move this code to `FormBase` so I don't have to put this line of code in every inherited form.

```
public class Form FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Program.MainForm.AddToFormSizes(this, this.Size);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I do that, `size` will have the size of `FormBase` in design-time, not the size of `formTest`.

Is there a way in `FormBase` to capture the size of `formTest` or any other form that inherited from `FormBase`?

for reference, this is the code of `AddToFormSizes` in the MainForm

```
private Dictionary<Form, Size> _formSizes = new Dictionary<Form, Size>();
public void AddToFormSizes(Form form, Size size)
{
    _formSizes.Add(form, form.Size);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do. The size of `formTest` is set (changed) in `formTest.InitializeComponent()` which `FormBase` knows nothing about. Before that happens, `formTest.Size` is the size derived from `FormBase`.

Comment: Move this thing (does it compile?): `Program.MainForm.AddToFormSizes(this, this.Size);` to `protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)`, after `base.OnHandleCreated(e);`. Inside your `base` Form.

Comment: @Jimi Good idea! That seems to work indeed. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Jimi Yes that compiles. `MainForm` is just a static reference in `Program.cs` to acces my mainform. I will try this suggestion thank you

Comment: BTW, you don't need a static reference of `MainForm` in `Program.cs`. You just need to make `AddToFormSizes()` static. You can call it from instance members inside `MainForm`.

Comment: @Jimi I need that reference for other things, not just for this method

Comment: @Jimi Your approach works, if you write in as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**:
Using a `Form` as base for other Forms, in the base class constructor, the **`this`** reference returns the **`Size`** of the base class instead of the `Size` of the derived class.

```
public class FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Program.MainForm.AddToFormSizes(this, this.Size);
    }
}
```

It's just a matter of following the sequence of events:

```
FormDerived derived = new FormDerived()
=> FormBase.InitializeComponent()
=> FormDerived.InitializeComponent()
derived.Show()
=> FormBase.OnHandleCreated()
```

---

Given the constructor of a Form derived from **`FormBase`**:

```
public class FormDerived : FormBase
{
     public FormDerived() => InitializeComponents();    
}
```

when the class is first created:

```
FormDerived derived = new FormDerived();
derived.Show();
```

the constructor of the base class (`FormBase`) is called first.
At this point, the **`this`** reference is set to **`FormDerived`**, but all the properties, including the `Name` and the Form's Caption (`Text`), are set to the values of the base class.
Hence, calling a method that uses **`this`** in the base class constructor:

```
Program.MainForm.AddToFormSizes(this, this.Size);
```

`this.Size` will return the Size of the base class, not the derived class.

The **`FormDerived`** constructor is called next. At this point, all the properties defined in the `InitializeComponent()` method will be set.

If the `AddToFormSizes()` method is moved to the derived class constructor, **`this`** will reference the expected values. But, the static method call must be inserted in each derived class of `FormBase`.

The `AddToFormSizes()` method can be instead moved to and called from the overridden **`OnHandleCreated()`** method of the base class, which will be called when the derived Form is first shown:

```
derived.Show();
```

will cause a call to **`FormBase.OnHandleCreated()`**.

At this point, the **`this`** reference is already set to the derived class and all the properties defined in  `InitializeComponent()` will be already set to the values of the derived class.
`Name`, `Text` and `Size` included, of course.

Here, **`this`** is **`FormDerived`** with all the properties set in its constructor:

```
public class FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnHandleCreated(e);
         Program.MainForm.AddToFormSizes(this, this.Size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution has solved my problem but another BIG trouble has started happening. I have created following two methods in the base form (CourierForm.cs):
`protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)`
`protected override void DestroyHandle()`
The `DestroyHandle()` method is added since i want to get and then save location of the closing form. Now when application is exited, following two exceptions occurs one by one:
[Could not load type](https://ibb.co/hsMqS9L)
[Object reference not set](https://ibb.co/9N7sNST)

Comment: When i open any form in designer, these two exceptions occur again and the form opens cluttered in the designer:
[Cluttered form in designer](https://ibb.co/qF4XM4b)

I guess the something has gone wrong. How to fix it?

Comment: @SyedIrfanAhmad Well, you did something wrong, but I cannot say what, you need to post the code you have used. Make another question, so you can show what you have done -- You shouldn't have anything related to Dependency Injection there, that's not something the designer can handle -- With `DestroyHandle()` I assume you mean `OnHandleDestroyed()`. Probably better override `OnFormClosed()`

Comment: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77230971/exception-occurs-when-form-i-opened-in-designer) created