# How to add a statement in Load event of many forms in Windows Forms C# application?

Tags: winforms, onload-event

I have created a feature in my Windows Forms application to open forms on their last position when they were closed. There are around 100+ forms in the application. All forms inherit from my own form say FormX. I coded the Shown and FormClosing events of the base form and all child forms open on their last saved position ... but the problem is: form first opens on the default location that is set at design time and then it moves to the last saved position. This creates a blink which is little annoying. The only good place is to re-position forms is the Load event but i can't find a smart way to place a statement in the Load event of all forms ... without opening 100+ forms. The idea is to make a method (to reposition form) in the base form and call it from the Load event of child forms. Please suggest if there is any smart way of doing it?
App details: Windows Form application in .Net 7, C#, Visual Studio 2022 (ver 17.7.4)

Any suggestion to place a statement in Load event of all forms without opening them individually.

Comment: Set the `StartPosition` to `Manual` and read here: [How to get the size of an inherited form in the base form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760332/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi My issue i not getting the size. I want to call a method of base form from derived forms to re-position and resize them. The last line of my question!!

Comment: Sure. That's exactly what that Q&A is about. Doesn't matter what you set, size or something else. Read the notes

Comment: @Jimi In base form, i have created a protected method and calling it in the Load event of two child forms and both forms open on their last closed position (not automatically but i have developed a mechanism for it. Form details are stored in DB and loaded when application is run):  
`base.SetFormPosition();`  
  
If i put this statement in 100+ forms (with minimal effort), my problem will be solved. So, i am looking for that "minimal effort".

Comment: If you did read the notes in that Q&A, then read them again, you missed the crucial point -- The Load event is irrelevant. You don't need to add anything to the derived Forms

Comment: @Jimi Thank you VERY much that you kept on pointing me to the treasure (link to your solution). Though i skipped through your solution, but since i was skeptical to the solution that i had in mind, i didn't read the full solution line by line. After you 3rd reminder, i decided to read every bit of it and your solution SOLVED my problem. So a big bundle of thanks and i appreciate your patience for keep pointing to the treasure.  Your solution to that question has also increased my knowledge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255511/discussion-between-syed-irfan-ahmad-and-jimi).