# Exception occurs when form i opened in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, object-reference

I wanted to open forms on their last closed locations. Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758166/how-to-get-the-size-of-an-inherited-form-in-the-base-form/55760332) helped and i created following two methods in base form (CourierForm.cs in my case). All forms inherit from CourierForm:

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e)

    FormLocation? fl = Wall.flb.Get(this.Name);
    if (fl is not null)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(fl.XLocation, fl.YLocation);
        this.Width = fl.Width;
        this.Height = fl.Height;
    }
}
```

```
protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Wall.lu is not null)
        Wall.flb.Register(this);  // Save form location details

    base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
}
```

Forms are opening and closing as desired but a strange thing has started happening. When i open any form, this exception occurs

[image]

and form opens cluttered in the designer like this

[image]

Cleaning project and solution and rebuilding the project hasn't helped fix the issue. When above two methods are commented and project is rebuilt, forms start opening normally in designer. I have used `OnHandleDestroyed()` to capture the event when forms are closed. In that event, i save form's location details.

App details: Windows Forms application in .Net 7, C#, VS 2022 (17.7.4).

how this issue can be fixed?

Comment: Did you try to debug form opening step-by-step, with breakpoint in OnHandleCreated? Simple NullReferenceException, and you need just to find what exactly is null in this few lines of code in example

Comment: Try to add `if (DesignMode) return;` after `base.OnHandleCreated(e)`, same for the other method -- If you're using Dependency Injection, don't rely on it at design-time

Comment: Instead of using `OnHandleCreated` and `OnHandleDestroyed` (which are Win32 events, and, although they take part in a form's lifecycle, do do other things as well), consider just persisting your status in a `FormClosing` handler and reading the status in the Form's `Load` handler.  That's the form lifecycle that all of the tooling expects you to be working in.  I do this all the time.

Comment: @Flydog57 You can read my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77216513/how-to-add-a-statement-in-load-event-of-many-forms-in-windows-forms-c-sharp-appl) and comments below it by Jimi why `OnHandleCreated()` is used

Comment: @Auditive Debugging with breakpoints led to nothing since no exception occurs while the app is running. App terminates nicely.
@Jimi I am not using any kind of dependency injection and placing those `if` has led to nothing. Here is what happens:
Forms open and close as expected and application terminates nicely. When i open any form (except the base form) in designer and then **close** its design tab, [this exception](https://ibb.co/qkk6Pk8) occurs. After that, no exception occurs while opening or closing other forms. Cleaning and rebuilding the project doesn't help. Same exception occurs.

Comment: Well, the exception is related to Dependency Injection, that's what the message is saying -- I suggested adding that check (`if (DesignMode) return;`) after both `base.OnHandleCreated(e)` and `base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);`. That of course means that any code you have must be executed only after the if condition (i.e., when you're NOT in Design-Mode)

Comment: @Jimi I did use the `if (DesignMode)` checks but somehow those statements got removed when i cleaned code to post here. In `base.OnHandleDestroyed(e)` method, there were two statements before the `if (DesignMode)` check. Moving those statements as you suggested has fixed the issue i.e. exception does not occur when form's design tab is closed.  
Usually exceptions occur when application is running. Mine was a weird exception that occurred when form's **design tab was closed**. For the sake of knowledge, can you elaborate **WHY** moving those statements fixed the issue?

Comment: `OnHandleCreated()` and `OnHandleDestroyed()` are related to the creation and destruction the window's Handle. These methods are evaluated, as it the Constructor of the window, when you generate a window in the Designer (windows' Handles are required). Other stuff, that is not related to the Designer, is not initialized. So any code you have in those methods cannot use references to stuff that's only available at run-time. When you have code there, verify whether you're in Design-Mode before trying to execute code that has references to run-time only objects / other elements

Comment: If you're interested in what happens when the VS Designer generates a visual instance your classes (Forms, UserControls, custom Controls etc.), you can use another instance of VS to debug the instance of VS where those classes are designer. Then you can put breakpoints in those methods and see what happens *under the hood*

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi), i had created two methods in my base form: `OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)` and `OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)`. These are events but not listed in form designer's list of events. So, i created them manually. Moving code statements after `if (DesignMode)` check fixed the exception i was having:

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    // In this method/event, "this" represents the derived class

    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if (DesignMode)
        return;

    // All code must be placed AFTER the "if (DesignMode)" check
    // otherwise exception may occur in form designer
}
```

```
protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
{
    // In this method/event, "this" represents the derived class

    base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
    if (DesignMode)
        return;

    // All code must be placed AFTER the "if (DesignMode)" check
    // otherwise exception may occur in form designer
}
```