# Managing Form Inheritance and InitializeComponent in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# WinForms application with a main form, let's call it MainForm, where I made various changes in the InitializeComponent method using the designer.

Now, I want to create a new form, let's call it SecondaryForm, which should inherit from MainForm to reuse its design and functionality. However, when I make changes in the designer of SecondaryForm, these changes are not being reflected in the compiled application.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
Duplicated MainForm.cs to SecondaryForm.cs.
Renamed InitializeComponent in SecondaryForm.cs to InitializeComponent1.
Changed the class declaration in SecondaryForm.cs to inherit from MainForm.
Updated references in SecondaryForm.cs to use SecondaryForm instead of MainForm.
Despite these changes, modifications in the designer of SecondaryForm are not affecting the compiled application.
```

Is there something I am overlooking, or is there a recommended approach for managing form inheritance and the InitializeComponent method in C# WinForms? Any guidance on how to structure my forms to achieve the desired behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Renamed InitializeComponent in SecondaryForm.cs to InitializeComponent1*: why? Don't do that. *Despite these changes, modifications in the designer of SecondaryForm are not affecting the compiled application*: meaning? What happened? What result do you see doing what? -- The notes here may be helpful: [How to get the size of an inherited form in the base form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760332/7444103)

Comment: I pressed F7 key and then double clicked on `public Form1()` reference and then in opened window i changed the InitializeComponent to InitializeComponent1 and then the designer got reseted which is what i want (to be honest i want a form at the start up and then after a button press on that first form the main form i designed first and before all of these shows up)

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say here. If you want to derive a Form from a base class that inherits the `Form` class, just create a new Form, then change the base class it derives from to the class name assigned to one of your Forms (`Form1 : Form` -> `Form2 : Form1`). If you want to use a Form as Template, then save it as Template (`Project->Export Template->Item Template` and pick the Form you care about). You can also Copy / Paste a Form object, then manually change its class name, both in the main class file and its Designer file. Don't change the name of `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: Ok thanks i'll try these steps.

Comment: When you store a Form as Template, you create new instance using the default tool (`Project->Add->Form (Windows Forms)`). If you're on .NET Framework, you can also use the Inherited Form Template (`Project->Add->Form (Windows Forms)->Inherited Form (Windows Forms)`)

Comment: Actually i have a form with a lot of controls (60 MB memory at startup). But after that i thought of this scenario that i create a new form with a button and when that button pressed the 60 MB form that i talked about at the first loads. now do you know how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking how to **manage Form inheritance**.

---

This is your "common" form to inherit. It has **[Common Button]** on it.

```
public partial class BaseFormWithButton : Form
{
    public BaseFormWithButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Base Form Designer**

[image: base form designer]

---

This is your form that inherits it:

```
public partial class FormInheritsBase : BaseFormWithButton
{
    public FormInheritsBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Inherited Form Designer**

[image: designer for Form that inherits]

[image: add button to Form that inherits]