# How to refactor old C# Windows Forms application implementing DRY rule?

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring, dry

I am working on an old C# Windows Forms application code base. There are many forms with same form controls, needing the same logic for validation and some other tasks.

Consider the following code:

```
var patientMobileData = new PatientData
{
    PatientID = patient.SickID,
    PatientMobileNumber = txbPatientMobileNumber.Text,
    InsuranceOrganization = Convert.ToInt32(txbBaseInsuranceID.Text)
};

bool isMobileNumberValid = AppointmentInputsChecker
    .CheckPatinetMobileNumber(patientMobileData, out message);

if (!isMobileNumberValid)
{
    txbPatientMobileNumber.Focus();
    return false;
}
```

In this code segment, I validate if the mobile number is required based on insurance organization, and if the mobile number is not duplicate. I refactored this code so all forms use `CheckPatinetMobileNumber` method to validate mobile number.

But this segment has to be repeated in all forms (12 forms). How can I made it even simpler, so for example a parent form will handle all this logic, and the other forms inherit from that?

I created a parent form implementing all this logic that is "NOT" dependent on form-controls. But as you can see, there are controls related to each form, like `txbPatientMobileNumber`. So I removed them from each from designer and added to the parent form. In other words, I removed this line of code from form_1.designer.cs:

```
internal Ema.CustomeTextBox.EmaTextBox txbPatientMobileNumber;
```

And added the `txbPatientMobileNumber` to the parent form class (not in designer, but inside the class before declaring the parent class constructor):

```
public Ema.CustomeTextBox.EmaTextBox txbPatientMobileNumber;
```

I didn't noticed any problem until now; but as each control has some event, like `onTextChange`, This made problem for me since I removed the control definition from each form designer.

Comment: You've already extracted the validation logic to another method. Simply calling the method from different forms is not a violation of DRY. Trying to go further with this by putting the field itself into a parent form is, IMO, not a great idea; I seriously doubt that will result in a design that is more maintainable.

Comment: The repeated code segments inside each form include nearly 1K code lines. Do you think I should keep these codes inside each form? I encountered problem making minor changes in these code segments multiple times.

Comment: If the code is simply there to "wire up" controls to methods (and not the methods themselves) yes, it is fine to repeat it on forms that have the same controls. This is idiomatic and normal for WinForms. You could come up with something clever if you really want but I really doubt other engineers will find that easier to work with.

Comment: So you mean I just extract methods independent from controls to a parent form and leave the other ones (like events dependent to controls) as they are?

Comment: Why does `CheckPatinetMobileNumber` method takes in an instance of `PatientData` when all it validates is the phone number?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, it should check if any other patient has the same mobile number. This is due to the fact that duplicate phone number, or national code is forbidden. It also requires insurance info to see if the mobile number is required or not.

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom control instead of moving all into a parent form?

Comment: @Fildor, would you please explain it a bit more? You mean creating a custom text box for example that has default events?

Comment: If you have many forms that basically looks and do the same thing with only small changes (like positions of elements or texts or whatever) you might also consider creating a single form that have some configurable parts (which are the differences between these forms) to replace them.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77508047/5438626) and see whether form inheritance might be helpful in your situation. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/77508047/5438626].

Comment: If you do use form inheritance, expect the pickiness of the forms designer to get in your way (no abstract classes, restrictions on non-default constructors, ...). Don't panic when it pops up and tells you that it's broken (just roll-back your latest chance once you've figure out how you offended the designer gods). It's a good idea to set up source control and to commit often

Comment: You may be interested in: [Develop custom controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/developing-custom-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). A control can contain numerous subcontrols, e.g. if you have a series of fields that appear on all of your forms, you can put them in a custom control, then put that control on the forms.

Comment: @JohnWu, almost 80 percent of the form controls are common in all forms. The application is for managing clinic information. There are Dental, Imaging, and some more clinics. I have group box for patient information. In this group box, not all controls are required for all clinic forms, but almost 80 percent. This is causing problem to create a custom `PatientGroupBox` and use it inside all forms.