# How can I avoid repeating this code in each of my forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the code below to round off the edges of my form.

I have several forms and this code is present on each of them

Is it possible to put this code in a class and call it in each of the forms to simplify?

I tried this but I get several errors.. Am I on the right track?

```
using Bybit.Net.Enums;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static MetroFramework.Drawing.MetroPaint;

namespace BasicProject
{

    public class Rounded
    {
        private int borderRadius = 30;
        private int borderSize = 4;
        private Color borderColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 185, 11);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
    private extern static void ReleaseCapture();
    [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    private extern static void SendMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
    private void FMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);
    }
    private GraphicsPath GetRoundedPath(Rectangle rect, float radius)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        float curveSize = radius * 3F;

        path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 180, 80);
        path.AddArc(rect.Right - curveSize, rect.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 270, 80);
        path.AddArc(rect.Right - curveSize, rect.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 0, 80);
        path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 80, 80);
        return path;
    }
    private void FormRegionAndBorder(Form form, float radius, Graphics graph, Color borderColor, float borderSize)
    {
        if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            using (GraphicsPath roundPath = GetRoundedPath(form.ClientRectangle, radius))
            using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
            using (Matrix transform = new Matrix())
            {
                graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                form.Region = new Region(roundPath);
                if (borderSize >= 2)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = form.ClientRectangle;
                    float scaleX = 1.0F - ((borderSize + 2) / rect.Width);
                    float scaleY = 1.0F - ((borderSize + 2) / rect.Height);

                    transform.Translate(borderSize / 1.6F, borderSize / 1.6F);
                    graph.DrawPath(penBorder, roundPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void FMain_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        FormRegionAndBorder(this, borderRadius, e.Graphics, borderColor, borderSize);
    }
```

Comment: "Is it possible to put this code in a class and call it in each of the forms to simplify?" Yes. You could create a static class and put the code in static methods (possibly even extension methods) that you call from your forms. You may well still need an event handler in each form, but I suspect that would be all. This would be a better question if instead of "Can I do this?" you'd tried, and shown what went wrong with your attempt.

Comment: @Jon Skeet,  OK thanks. I updated my question

Comment: "I tried this but I get several errors" - what errors? Currently you've presented code which has methods just directly in a namespace declaration instead of within a class, and that won't work... you specifically said "Is it possible to put this code in a class" but you haven't done that...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, The errors are undeclared variables... I'm probably doing it wrong but if I'm asking the question here it's because I don't know how to put the code in a class to simplify. All I can do is the code I presented

Comment: Here's the official link with a detailed example if you want to try Jon's suggestion of writing an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: You are going to have issues with 'this'.  You want the handle of the sender not the handle of the class.  I would do following : var s = sender as Control;  var handle = s.Handle;

Comment: You probably (given the names used and *style*) took that code from here: [How can I draw a rounded rectangle as the border for a rounded Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56533229/7444103). The answer was more about handling derived Forms, so the code that generates the rounded region is in the derived class, to showcase how different settings in different classes work together. But you can move that code to the base class, then all derived Forms will inherit the layout

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the link, I have to put the "baseForm class" code in one class and the other in the constructor?

Comment: As mentioned, you can move all the code that generates the rounded Region, which is in the derived class (`frmRoundCorners` in that Q&A) to the base class (`baseForm`). Then all derived classes will inherit that behavior, without adding any other code

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks for answering, sorry if I'm asking stupid questions as I'm a beginner... after moving the code from the "frmRoundCorners" class to the base class (baseForm) how do I call this class from my form?

Comment: You don't call anything. `frmRoundCorners` inherits from its base class, `baseForm`, as the latter derives from its base class, `Form`. You just create a new instance of `frmRoundCorners`. See the notes here: [How to get the size of an inherited form in the base form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760332/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks, so I tried like you said but my forms aren't rounded. Knowing that OnMouseDown(), OnMouseMove(), OnPaint() have no reference. Here's the class I tried: https://pastebin.com/iwq5JkUw

Comment: You copied the entire `frmRoundCorners` class inside the `baseForm` class. You have to **move the code** of the former inside the latter, so it's the base Form that determines the layout. Then all other Form classes that derived from this base class inherit this behavior -- I suggest you stop for a moment and get acquainted with [Object-Oriented programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/oop) (see the other topics in the menu on the left)

Comment: @Jimi, What do you mean by "Move"? is it "Replace"? if so then it still doesn't work... please have a look: https://pastebin.com/nNr4wyuh
Thanks for the link, I'll read it carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I understood, it is that you need to use the same code in several models without repeating writing this code.
If you want to reuse the same code in multiple forms without repeating it, you can follow a simple approach. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a base form: Start by creating a base form that contains the code you want to reuse. This form will serve as a template for other forms.
2. Remove unnecessary properties: Remove any properties or controls from the base form that are specific to a particular form. Keep the code that you want to reuse.
3. Inherit from the base form: In each form where you want to reuse the code, inherit from the base form instead of the default Form class. This way, the derived forms will have access to the code in the base form.

Here's an example to illustrate this concept:

```
// BaseForm.cs
public class BaseForm : Form
{
    // Add the code you want to reuse here
    public void CommonMethod()
    {

    }
}

// Form1.cs
public class Form1 : BaseForm
{

}

// Form2.cs
public class Form2 : BaseForm
{

}
```

In this example, BaseForm is the base form that contains the common code. Form1 and Form2 are derived forms that inherit from BaseForm. They will have access to the CommonMethod() defined in the base form.

By following this approach, you can reuse the same code across multiple forms without having to repeat it. Any changes or updates made to the code in the base form will automatically reflect in all the derived forms.