# Property values defined in Property Window stll have their default values in OnLoad and constructor of my UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, properties, onload

I would like to be able to use the properties I set in the Properties Window of Visual Studio in my UserControl, but I get the default value of the property back, such as 0 or null.
I tried this in the constructor and the Onload of my UserControl in C#.

SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsBase is based on a UserControl
I tried this:

```
public abstract class SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsBase : SGscrollBoxSyncFusion
{
    protected SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsBase()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Size.ToString());
    }
```

and this

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    MessageBox.Show(Size.ToString());
}
```

But this both returns (Width=0, Height =0) and it should be (Width=252, Height =126)

When I try this in my Form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sgScrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll.Size.ToString());            
}
```

this returns (Width=252, Height =126) and that is what I want.

How do I get the expected result with code inside of my UserControl?
I use C# with WinForms.

Edit: You can think of the classes as regular UserControls. SyncFusion means that there are SyncFusion scroll bars on the controls.

SGscrollBoxSyncFusion is a custom control based on a UserControl.
The derived class is an SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsBase which is abstract.
The class sgScrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll is derived from this class and has a public constructor.

This is the class definition:

```
public class SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll : SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsBase
```

This is the constructor:

```
public SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll() 
{ ...... }
```

---

Edit 2:
To Simplify my problem I have created a UserControl class from scratch.

```
namespace UserControls
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show(Number.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I placed this control on my form and set the Number property in the Properties Window of the form designer to 100. Still the result is 0.
How is this possible?

Comment: Why is the Constructor of the derived UserControl defined as `protected` and not, e.g., `public` or `protected internal`? Is `SGscrollBoxSyncFusion`  actually a UserControl?

Comment: SGscrollBoxSyncFusion is a custom control based on a UserControl.
The derived class is an SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsBase which is abstract.
The class sgScrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll is derived from this and has a public constructor

This is the class definition:
public class SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll : SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsBase

This is the constructor:
public SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll()
{
         ......
}

Comment: That doesn't explain the access modifier of the class Constructor. Anyway, read the notes here: [How to get the size of an inherited form in the base form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760332/7444103)

Comment: You show ctor abbreviated to `public SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll() { ...... }`. Are you calling the `InitializeComponent()` in your subclass to read the designer file at that level?(It's not a virtual method)?

Comment: I don't use InitializeComponent in the classes i have created in this project. I create my classes with my own code.
Because my question is very specific to my project I create a simplified explanation of my problem after Edit 2 in the question. Please look at Edit 2. I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: How are you supposed to get the Property value assigned **in the Form's Designer**, in the Constructor of the UserControl? The value of the Property is assigned **after** the UC has been created, so the first time you see the value assigned **in the Form's Designer** is in the `OnHandleCreated` override. You didn't read what is described in the Q&A I've linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jimi. That was the answer I need. It works now!

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    MessageBox.Show(Number.ToString()); //Gives 100 and that is correct
}
```

In my question I used OnLoad and it didn't work while OnLoad is called later than OnhandleCreated. The reason I guess is that de Size was set in the baseclass to 0. Thanks for the help.

Edit:

The form designer in my real project with the SGscrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll class puts the add of the control before the setting of the properties of the control. And that was a reason it didn't work.

This is code from InitializeComponent:

```
this.tabPageAdvPhotoRoll.Controls.Add(this.sgScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBoxForPhotoRoll);
...
this.sgScrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll.LinkedZoomedImageScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBox = this.sgScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBoxForPhotoRoll;
```

I switched this to:

```
this.sgScrollBoxSyncFusionThumbnailsPhotoRoll.LinkedZoomedImageScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBox = this.sgScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBoxForPhotoRoll;
...
this.tabPageAdvPhotoRoll.Controls.Add(this.sgScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBoxForPhotoRoll);
```

And now it works. The Add method triggers the OnHandleCreated EventHandler. In the first situation the LinkedZoomedImageScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBox property was not set when OnHandleCreated was triggered.

In the second situation it is set before the OnHandleCreated was triggered.

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if (LinkedZoomedImageScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBox != null)
    {
        AddSubComponents(new Size(200, 200), 3, LinkedZoomedImageScrollBoxSyncFusionPictureBox, "G:\\Path\\To\\Images");
    }
}
```